# Android Mapbox Mapview shows white screen before rendering maps

Tags: android, android-layout, mapbox, android-mapview, mapbox-android

Mapbox Mapview shows a white screen flash before the Mapview is rendered. The flash stays for like 500ms after which the map is displayed. I am adding Mapview dynamically to my FrameLayout((addView()) at run time. Below is the code snippet. Please help !

```
private fun initializeMapBoxMap() {
    val mapView = MapView(context) // create new mapview 
    innerLayout.addView(mapView) // add mapView to the FrameLayout
    mapView.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
           // white screen shown at this point for 500 ms 
           mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.DARK) {
              // white screen gone at this point
           }

    }
}
```

Screenshot Link : [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL6Ix.jpg)

Comment: Is the white screen occurring on an emulator or a physical device? If you've only seen this on an emulator, I'd recommend testing on a physical device as well since emulator performance is known to be sub-optimal when compared to actual hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the color to another with:
mapboxMapOptions.foregroundLoadColor(int color)

we try to mask that the glsurfaceview has loaded but we don't have any content to render as we are still loading the style definition. instead of loading resources, having them offline will also improve the UX.

Credits to tobrun for the info
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16367